# Data transfer between ATmega16 microcontroller and Linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, usb-drive

Can any one tell me how can I know status of any pin of an ATmega16 microcontroller using Ubuntu?

When I connect ATmega16 to my system a file in `/dev/` is created by name `ttyUSB0`. I am using an USB-to-serial converter in order to connect the ATmega16.

Comment: You likely will need to write code on your ATMega16 that outputs pin status over the serial port. This (but not as presently written) might be more on-topic for EE.SE.

Comment: While connecting to a device from a unix machine is on-topic here, this may require more action on the µc than we can advise you on. This question would fit better on [the proposed embedded systems site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50195/embedded-programming-and-design?referrer=2lF5gAel4peFRGSmvGLajg2). It may or may not fit on [electronics.se].

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to write a program for the ATmega which can report pin status over the serial port.